# How to decode response of eth_getlogs with PHP?

Tags: php, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I succeeded in getting the contract log from infura with eth_getlogs.

But I don't know how to decode the retrieved data with PHP.

Please tell me how to decode retrieved data with PHP.

PHP code

```php
$my_server_url = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/APIKey";
$ch = curl_init($my_server_url);
$data = array(
    'jsonrpc' => '2.0',
    'id' => 1,
    'method' => 'eth_getLogs',
    'params' => array(array(
        "fromBlock" => "0x949986",
        "toBlock"   => "latest",
        "topics" => ["0x70d79747edd06ece6bf0a5ee4429d0138fa4ccbeefaea4d21e0e511e9d81b094"],
        "address"   => "0xf0A0293D762aF2AC36E57613D42aC36773eEAf51"
    ))
);
$payload = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $result;
```

Retrieved Data:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":[{"address":"0xf0a0293d762af2ac36e57613d42ac36773eeaf51","blockHash":"0x348b7e3dcf6c76c483f872851650b7aed8f2f6d6042207b8f55e13a6c52a19cd","blockNumber":"0x949986","data":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000973616d706c653132330000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e6372656174652073756363657373000000000000000000000000000000000000","logIndex":"0x85","removed":false,"topics":["0x70d79747edd06ece6bf0a5ee4429d0138fa4ccbeefaea4d21e0e511e9d81b094","0x0000000000000000000000008790dc53157f7090b85785fc107360a23ad63a13"],"transactionHash":"0x0b9544631e221ed9569aae363d272a54dc853cf7f84610bda3c828c6f181784e","transactionIndex":"0x4a"},{"address":"0xf0a0293d762af2ac36e57613d42ac36773eeaf51","blockHash":"0xc287eb38486a137e33a85f641efdcc1f57b90d3f7889709503e53fec54657ff0","blockNumber":"0x9499f2","data":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000973616d706c65313233000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000137365742061646472657373207375636365737300000000000000000000000000","logIndex":"0x60","removed":false,"topics":["0x70d79747edd06ece6bf0a5ee4429d0138fa4ccbeefaea4d21e0e511e9d81b094","0x0000000000000000000000008790dc53157f7090b85785fc107360a23ad63a13"],"transactionHash":"0xae01b5c746ce2229c566682208b7af1f0520e094dfc2adef69f22eb8dd6f3bf2","transactionIndex":"0x4a"}]}
```

I want to decode data section of retrieved data.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE: Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help:)

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

I followed your advice and added the code.

Comment: Hi @programmer_someone123, did you succeed? I have the same question.